# Java- How to use For Loop with (Multidimensional) Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was able to use for loop with int multidimensional arrays but I'm unable to reproduce it with multi arrays.

```
public class array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] words = new String[2][3];
    words[0][0] = "a";
    words[0][1] = "b";
    words[0][2] = "c";
    words[1][0] = "d";
    words[1][1] = "e";
    words[1][2] = "f";
   }
}
```

Would love some help on how to iterate that

For reference, this was what I did for int

```
int[][] multi = {
        {3, 4, 5},
        {2, 3, 5, 6, 7},
        {112, 3}
    };
    for (int row = 0; row < multi.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < multi[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(multi[row][col] + " ");
```

Comment: show sample code which fails for you

Comment: `for (String[] word : words) { for (String character : word) {...} }`

Comment: try nested loop. `for(int i=0;i<rolSizei++) { for(int j=0;j<colSize;j++) {words[i][j] ...}}`

Comment: Please edit you question to provide the complete code: somebody who wants to help you should be able to copy your code, paste it in an editor and run it without having to add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, adapt the for loops, dont forget every row is an array as well.....

```
    String[][] words = new String[2][3];
    words[0][0] = "a";
    words[0][1] = "b";
    words[0][2] = "c";
    words[1][0] = "d";
    words[1][1] = "e";
    words[1][2] = "f";
    for (int row = 0; row < words.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < words[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.println(words[row][col]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the method I was trying to accomplish, but it seems I inadvertenly tried to mix the other suggestion above (nested foreach loop) with this one. It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you can do the following iterate and print the 2d:

```
Stream.of(words).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

Output:
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Just print as one dimensional arrays using Arrays.toString()

```
Stream.of(words).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

Output:

[a, b, c]
[d, e, f]
```

Comment: Not exactly. Instead of `map(Arrays::toString)` you would want to use `flatMap(Stream::of)`. :-)

Comment: Corrected my answer based on ur comment

Answer (score 0):

> How to use For Loop with (Multidimensional) Array of Strings?

```
String[][] words = new String[2][3];
    words[0][0] = "a";
    words[0][1] = "b";
    words[0][2] = "c";
    words[1][0] = "d";`
    words[1][1] = "e";
    words[1][2] = "f";
```

**Using nested for each loop**

One way to accomplish such task is to use nested for each loop, however having said there are other solutions to accomplish the same task.

```
for(String[] word : words)){
 for(String currentWord : word)System.out.println(currentWord); // this is just explanatory, which you can change with what ever you wish to accomplish with this loop.
}
```

Another way:

**Using nested for loop**

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < 2; i++) {
 for(int j = 0 ;j < 3; j++) {
    System.out.println(words[i][j]); // this is just explanatory, which you can change with what ever you wish to accomplish with this loop.
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The nested foreach loop above works just fine, and is actually preferable now that I know it. I did attempt something like this, but I only declared the first part 
    'for(String[]word:words){'
and then jumped to print. 
I tried the nested for loop which is the method I was working on but I couldn't get it to work with the code you suggested. I'm not sure if this is because of rowSize & columnSize because changing and using the suggestion below worked.

Comment: @JeffOgah the nested for loop does work. I will update the answer to show you exactly what you need.