# How do I compare numbers in a nested array

Tags: java

For example if I have a two dimensional array that looks like:

10 2 5 4

6 3 7 8

How would I be able to check if each element is larger than each other?
In this case I would get 10 > 2, 5 > 4, and 6 > 3.

Comment: To clarify your question, you're trying to compare every element in an odd-numbered column with the element directly to its right to see which is bigger?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop?

Comment: Let me know if you'd like me to explain further what using a for loop for this would look like.

Comment: Please provide some java code and show the exact output that you need in your example.

Comment: Consider answers like this one for how to write loops for nested arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494108/java-how-to-use-for-loop-with-multidimensional-array-of-strings

Answer (score 1):

If I am not not wrong you need code which would compare odd matrix position with even .
Kindly find below code which would be adequate for your goal.

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] a = {{2,3,4,5},{16,12,3,6}};

        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            int i=0;
            while(i<a[j].length && i+1 < a[j].length)
            {
                if(a[j][i] > a[j][i+1])
                {
                    System.out.println(a[j][i] +" is Greater than "+a[j][i+1] );
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(a[j][i] +" is Lesser than "+a[j][i+1] );
                }
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this was helpful.